# How freeing memory during viewController transition

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, swift, sprite-kit

I explain my problem.

I just made a game with 3 views.

1. the game presentation with a playbutton
2. the game scene
3. the game over scene with a button to play again or go back to the presentation scene.

My problem is when there is a transition between two scenes, the active memory will be 30MB more and each scene transition will increase the active memory about 30MB and will never decrease.

How can I fix it and release memory ?

Thank you all

My transition code :

```
// Transition in presentationViewController file
func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{

    println("transition")
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as UIViewController

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
    UIView.transitionFromView(
        window.rootViewController!.view,
        toView: secondViewController.view,
        duration: 0.65,
        options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
        completion: {
            finished in window.rootViewController = secondViewController
    })
}


// transition in GameScene file

func removeCountDownTimerView()
{

    defaults.setInteger(balloonDestroyed, forKey: "score")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let gameOverScene: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverViewController") as UIViewController
    let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    vc?.presentViewController(gameOverScene, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

// transition in gameOverViewController file

func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("play transition")
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as UIViewController


    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
    UIView.transitionFromView(
        window.rootViewController!.view,
        toView: secondViewController.view,
        duration: 0.65,
        options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
        completion: {
            finished in window.rootViewController = secondViewController
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as UIViewController
```

This code is creating new ViewController each time user press the button. I advise you to use singletone pattern for this.

```
private let _SomeManagerSharedInstance = GameViewController() 
class GameOverViewController {
class var sharedInstance: GameOverViewController {
       return _GameOverViewController
}
```

You can also create a private class method for instantiating the View Controller from storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm a new programer (it's my first app) where have I to add your code? Can you explain it to understand?